# How can I align the top of a parbox when placing it using a put command?

Tags: pdftex, overpic, parbox

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\numberLeftOffset}{3}
    \newcommand{\numberTopOffset}{7}
    \newcommand{\numberSuitOffset}{7}

    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/strike.jpg}
        \put (7,93) {\parbox{2in}{foobar}}
    \end{overpic}

    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/strike.jpg}
        \put (7,93) {\parbox{2in}{foobar \\ barfoo}}
    \end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

In the two `overpic` environments, the first argument to `put` is the same. However, because the second parbox has two lines while the first one has only one, the text `foobar` is higher in the second image than the first one.

Is it possible to make the `foobar` in both images appear in the same vertical position without manually tweaking the coordinates given to `put` until they visually match?

Note that I can bound the height of the parbox if that is useful. I've already tried setting the height and using a vfill but that appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\parbox[t]`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\numberLeftOffset}{3}
    \newcommand{\numberTopOffset}{7}
    \newcommand{\numberSuitOffset}{7}

    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{example-image}
        \put (7,93) {\parbox[t]{2in}{foobar}}
    \end{overpic}
\qquad
    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{example-image}
        \put (7,93) {\parbox[t]{2in}{foobar \\ barfoo}}
    \end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

The reference point, with respect to which the `93` placement is done, is the baseline of the top line in the parbox.

Without `[t]`, the reference point is the middle vertical point of the parbox.

[image]